# VB Equivalent of C# Event Creation

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, events

I'm trying to extend the GridView class to always show the header and footer even when the datasource is empty by using the code I found online ([link](http://weblogs.asp.net/joewrobel/archive/2008/01/30/a-more-elegant-solution-to-display-gridview-header-and-footer-when-the-data-source-is-empty.aspx)).  However, the code is written in C# but I use VB.

What is the VB equivalent of the following?

```
public event MustAddARowHandler MustAddARow;
```

Is there a way around VB.NET not allowing events to return a type?

Also, I cannot convert the following function because of the error below.

**Code:**

```
Protected Function OnMustAddARow(ByVal data As IEnumerable) As IEnumerable
    If MustAddARow = Nothing Then 'Error on MustAddARow'
        Throw New NullReferenceException("The datasource has no rows.  You " _
                                        & "must handle the 'MustAddARow' Event.")
    End If
    Return MustAddARow(data) 'Error on MustAddARow'
End Function
```

**Error:**  Public Event MustAddARow(data As System.Collections.IEnumerable)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the answer of my other post ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694095/convert-c-with-typed-events-to-vb-net)), I compiled the C# code into a DLL which I use in my VB Code.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
Public Event MustAddRow(data As IEnumerable)
```

Comment: What about "MustAddARowHandler" in the original line?

Comment: The VB.Net compiler will automatically generate the delegate type.

Comment: SLaks is right, but there is another way: Public Event MustAddRow as MustAddRowHandler

Comment: Adding "as MustAddRowHandler" causes the following error: Events cannot have a return type.

Comment: True, because in VB events cannot return anything. They only raise, add handlers, and remove handlers. I'm surprised that in C# they can. I'd appreciate if someone with c# knowledge would explain exactly what is going on in that code you linked.

Comment: @M.A. Hanin, see this SO post for an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356488/ccreating-multicast-delegate-with-boolean-return-type/1356524#1356524

Answer (score 2):

***Note:** This answer is actually wrong. My bad. The syntax shown is correct (which is why I won't delete this answer right away), but it won't compile, since events -- which are usually multi-cast delegates -- aren't allowed to return a value in VB.NET.*

---

**Event declaration:**

```
Public Event MustAddRow As MustAddRowHandler
```

**Delegate type declaration:** (which is the prerequisite for the above)

```
Public Delegate Function MustAddRowHandler(ByVal data As IEnumerable) As IEnumerable
```

Comment: Error: Events cannot be declared with a delegate type that has a return type.

Comment: What are multicast delegates and how do they differ from unicast delegates? in VB, all delegates have an invokation list, that is - they can all invoke multiple target methods.

Comment: @M.A. Hanin: AFAIK, delegates are multicast by default. I'm not even sure if unicast delegates can be defined at all, since the .NET classes that implement delegates are protected in special ways. I can't give a definite answer on this, but I suspect VB.NET simply will accept only `Sub` delegates, i.e. those not returning any values. -- See also my comment at the other answer.