# Showing Gridview when no data present in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, gridview

I'm working on a ASP.NET website project using VB.NET as backend code.
I was looking for a way to show the header/footer of a gridview even if no data is present.

I'd like to use this solution as it looks pretty clean (although it's written in C#):
[link](http://weblogs.asp.net/joewrobel/archive/2008/01/30/a-more-elegant-solution-to-display-gridview-header-and-footer-when-the-data-source-is-empty.aspx)

I have converted the code using an online tool, resulting in: http://pastebin.com/qy8a2ejA

This however shows an error on line 77: "Events cannot be declared with a delegate type that has a return type"

Can someone help me convert this piece of code? Thanks :)

Comment: If the datatable you are binding the gridview to is empty. The gridview will still display the header/footer, at least in my experience this has been true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4, you could use this [GridView.ShowHeaderWhenEmpty Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.showheaderwhenempty.aspx). As far as converting the code the VB .NET, [take a look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694095/convert-c-with-typed-events-to-vb-net).

Comment: Thanks, that post suggested some useful workarounds. Eventually I used the method on this site: [link](http://gis.utah.gov/code-c-/c-displaying-an-empty-gridview)